# Apps Script - Achieving Multiple Locks on Different Parts of Script

Tags: google-apps-script, locking

I am trying to limit concurrent use of apps script for different parts of the same script, but no matter what I do, one lock will lock the whole thing down.  Here's my sample script:

```
function lockTest(event) {
  var r_eventRange = event.range;
  var value = r_eventRange.getValue();
  
  if (value == "A"){
    var lock1 = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock1.waitLock(10000);
    //do stuff
    lock1.releaseLock();
  } else if (value == "B") {
    var lock2 = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock2.waitLock(10000);
    //do different stuff
    lock2.releaseLock();
  }
}
```

Function 'lockTest' is triggered by an onEdit event.  The intent for this script is that there can be two values: "A", and "B".  If I get consecutive calls where both have `value` "A", then force the calls to wait to execute one at a time.  Same thing if I get consecutive calls where both have `value` "B".  But if I get consecutive calls where `value` is "A" in one and "B" in the other, then go ahead and let the code run consecutively without waiting.

However, the with this script the 'lock service' will not allow consecutive runs regardless of the `value`.  In other words, if the first call has `value` "A", and the second call comes before the first is done but the `value` is "B", the lock service is forcing the second call to wait for the first call to complete even though the locks are supposed to be different.

Is it possible to control the locking on different parts of the script?

---

Basically, I need `value` "A" to trigger `lock1` which edits a specific set of shared resources.  `value` "B" should trigger `lock2` which edits a completely different set of shared resources than `lock1`.   That means that `lock1` and `lock2` should be able to run at the same time because the resources they edit are completely different.  In fact I need them to run at the same time because `lock1` will be triggered a lot more frequently than `lock2` and `lock1` takes only about 2 seconds to execute.  `lock2` is triggered much less frequently but takes 30-150 seconds to execute.  So I need `lock1` to be able to run even if `lock2` is already running because otherwise `lock1` will either time out or there could be so many instances of `lock1` waiting in line while `lock2` finishes that the 'lock service' will start throwing errors.

Interestingly enough, if I put a logger before the if() statement, I get logs instantly every time an edit event happens - meaning that the 'lock service' in only locking down the if statement and not the lines before it.

Google's documentation for 'lock service' says

> getScriptLock() Gets a lock that prevents any user from concurrently
> running a section of code. A code section guarded by a script lock
> cannot be executed simultaneously regardless of the identity of the
> user.

It seems like from this that we should be able to lock specific sections of code.  I just can't figure out how to designate what those individual sections are.  I assumed the `releaseLock()` method would tell it where to end the section.  And maybe it does - I'm concerned that the 'lock service' doesn't support designating multiple independent locks, which is what I need here.

---

According to Oleg's suggestion:

```
function lockTest(event) {
  var r_eventRange = event.range;
  var value = r_eventRange.getValue();
  
  if (value == "A"){
    checkFormatting();
  } else {
    doAction();
  }
}

function checkFormatting(){
  var lock1 = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock1.waitLock(10000);
  //do stuff
  lock1.releaseLock();
}

function doAction(){
  var lock2 = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock2.waitLock(10000);
  //do different stuff
  lock2.releaseLock();
}
```

Unfortunately I'm having the same issue with the above code.

Comment: Can I ask you about the method for executing the function of `lockTest`?

Comment: it's essentially an onEdit function triggered by the edit event.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the method for executing the script. From this situation, for example, when `value` is "A" by executing the script, the script is locked until the script is finished. When new event is fired during the script is locking, the new event waits until the lock is released. From this situation, I cannot understand about `In other words, ...`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and goal?

Comment: LockService locks the script regardless of the values it's passed, and you can't get past that. Only different documents or different users will be able to run concurrent executions of the same script depending on the [type of lock used](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock#lockservice)

Comment: @RafaGuillermo well, the docs do say that it can be used to prevent concurrent runs of a section of code, not the script itself, so I wonder whether this is possible. I assume that by "section" they mean a context, something that can be pushed on the stack. This would also explain why `if` statement does not do anything in terms of locking execution (how would it, after all?)

Comment: @Tanaike, I added more clarification to my post regarding your question.

Comment: @OlegValter, indeed the lock service is supposed to allow us to lock specific sections of code.  I tested this with the logger and updated my post with the results.

Comment: Well, the only "section" I know of in JavaScript is "execution context", so it makes sense that the lock is obtained by-function, but is released as soon as one calls a `releaseLock` method. Try making A and B handlers separate functions and acquire lock *inside* them, I think you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @OlegValter, I kind of thought so too, but when I tested it, it did the same thing.  I added the script I tested to my post just to make sure I'm understanding your suggestion correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I confirmed that the discussions have advanced. From the flow of discussions, I thought that it will lead to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you do. It seems the locks provided by `LockService` are singletons, and thus your `lock.waitLock()` calls will always wait irregardless of where the lock was grabbed initially.

I recommend you look at this library providing "named locks" which is what you are looking for here. Have not used it yet, but looks promising.

https://ramblings.mcpher.com/gassnippets2/using-named-locks-with-google-apps-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

`LockService` provides a **single** mutex  (aka lock) which you can lock/unlock.

Recall that multiple JS runtimes can run in your Google Sheet at a time. The guarantee that `LockService` provides is that when `waitLock()` succeeds, you **know** that you are the only JS runtime that has obtained the lock. All other runtimes are either doing something which doesn't care about the lock, or are waiting for you to release the lock.

```js
const mutex = LockService.getScriptLock();
const TIMEOUT_MS = 10*1000;

function doStuff() {}

function doTheFirstThing() {
  // Process some local data. Don't need the lock yet.
  doStuff();  

  // Increment a cell. We definitely need the lock here,
  // because we need to read and write in a row without
  // somebody changing the value under our nose.
  mutex.waitLock(TIMEOUT_MS);
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getRange('A1');
  range.setValue(range.getValue()+1);
  mutex.releaseLock();
}
function doTheSecondThing() {
  // Process some different local data.
  // We also don't care about the lock yet.

  // Decrement a cell. We definitely need the lock here,
  // because we need to read and write in a row without
  // somebody changing the value under our nose.
  mutex.waitLock(TIMEOUT_MS);
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getRange('A1');
  range.setValue(range.getValue()-1);
  mutex.releaseLock();
}
```

So a **critical section** is not defined really by a code block persay - it is defined by where you lock and unlock a specific mutex. In my example, `doTheFirstThing()` and `doTheSecondThing()` share a critical section. What you can do to achieve named locks (and thus distinct critical sections) is maintain a (synchronized) map of (lockName => isLocked) and use the one global lock you get to access said map.

However, be wary of performance here, as locking any named lock will lock the global lock.

Comment: Okay technically there are a few locks that LockService provides, but I `getScriptLock()` has the most obvious semantics so that's the only one I'm considering here

Comment: I guess if you really needed it, you could parallelize your script across multiple users, each who get their own lock